# How to create this typography style?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, typography, photoshop-effects, effects

I saw this book cover and I loved the font of the title, I tried using photoshop with different styles like bevel and emboss but nothing looked like the photo, I was wondering if anyone could show me how to create this type of typography style for "The Young Elites" and "The Rose Society" I love the look of it and would love to know how to recreate it! Thanks[image]

Answer (score 4):

The effects are much more likely fined tuned than what I am about to show you but this should give you a starting point. This can be done in most photo editing programs but the following steps are for Photoshop.

1) Write out your text

2) Based on your style, find a picture with texture to place above your text layer. I used a picture of wolfs fur.

[image: wolf texture]

3) Select the textured layer and go to Layer -> Create Clipping Mask.

4) Add Bevel & Emboss to the text layer. Double click on the text layer in the Layers Panel to open up the Layer Style window and choose Bevel & Emboss. Also add a slight drop shadow to the text.

[image: Bevel options]

Result

[image: The result]